# How to post image in react-native with require and variable in the path

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

I am building an app which need to load images from server and display them after fetch, but when I try to load the image in react-native, the path is not working, so I try to add "require" before put the path into the  component, but result in an error,
I try to clone a new array of objects before I map the "book_cover" into
<Image
style={styles.bookSample}

```
            source={item.book_cover}
          />
```

```
[{"author": "aaa", "book_cover": "../../bookImage/bookcover/三隻小豬-1.jpeg"}, {"author": "bbb", "book_cover": "../bookImage/bookcover/白雲和彩虹-1.jpeg"}, {"author": "ccc", "book_cover": "../bookImage/bookcover/新玩具-1.jpeg"}]
const newbookInfo = bookInfo.map(e => ({ ...e, book_cover: require(e.book_cover) }));
```

Answer (score 0):

At present, the `require` doesn't work with dynamic paths/variables. It requires the static file path fed to it.

A formal justification for the problem is:

`The basic functionality of require is that it reads a JavaScript file, executes the file, and then proceeds to return the exports object`

To solve your problem, you might want to add prerequired image modules to your `book_cover` attribute. like:

```
[{"author": "aaa", "book_cover": require("../../bookImage/bookcover/三隻小豬-1.jpeg")}...]
```

Comment: thx, but what is the datatype that I can store with this :require(path),I am using postgresql

Comment: Store image urls only, considering you are saving the actual images on some storage server like Amazon s3, google storage which in turn will give you image url. Just save that to your DB.